# 403 statuses on nginx at FreeBSD

Tags: nginx, freebsd, php-fpm, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to switch from an Apache hosting solution to nginx with php-fpm on FreeBSD 9.2.

I'm rewriting my script for creating vHosts and stuff for nginx now and get 403 statuses when I try to access the vHost.

I'm struggling for hours now and can't get no clue, which permissions to set. Do you have any ideas?

**Here's my createvhost.sh:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

DOMAIN="example.com"
PHP_USER="chris_www"
PHP_GROUP="$PHP_USER"

NGINX_USER="www"
NGINX_GROUP="$NGINX_USER"
ADMIN_EMAIL="root@example.com"

NGINX_CONF_FOLER="/usr/local/etc/nginx"
PHP_FPM_CONF_FOLDER="/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d"

WEBROOT="/www/vhosts"

IP="10.0.0.4"

VHOST_PORT=9000
source $WEBROOT/config/vhost_port.conf


## Create user and add it to $NGINX_GROUP
echo "Creating user and adding it to group $NGINX_GROUP"
pw user add $PHP_USER -s /sbin/nologin
pw group mod $PHP_GROUP -m $NGINX_GROUP

echo "Creating neccessary folders"
mkdir -p $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN/{conf,www,log,tmp,certs,sessions}

chown root:$PHP_USER $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN
chmod 750 $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN
chown $PHP_USER:$PHP_USER $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN/*
chown -R $PHP_USER:$PHP_USER $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN/www/*
chmod 755 $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN/*
chmod 550 $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN/conf

## Create template for ssl cert creation
cat > $WEBROOT/$DOMAIN/conf/ssleay.cnf  $NGINX_CONF_FOLER/sites-avaliable/$DOMAIN.conf  $PHP_FPM_CONF_FOLDER/$DOMAIN.conf  $WEBROOT/config/vhost_port.conf

echo "Restarting nginx"
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx restart

echo "Restarting php-fpm"
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/php-fpm restart

echo "Finished."
```

**Here's my nginx.conf:**

```
user www www;
worker_processes 8;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile    8192;

events {
   use   kqueue;
   worker_connections   8192;
}

http {
    #set_real_ip_from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    real_ip_header 'X-Forwarded-For';

    # Logging
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $status "$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"
"$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log crit;

    # MIME-Types
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

# Allgemeines
    index index.php index.htm;
    server_tokens on;
    client_header_timeout 5;
    client_body_timeout 10;
    client_max_body_size 16m;
    ignore_invalid_headers on;
    send_timeout 10;

    # Performance-Tuning
    sendfile on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    tcp_nopush   on;
    aio   sendfile;
    keepalive_timeout   5;

 # DDoS-Bekämpfung
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=antiddos:10m rate=1r/s;

    # GZIP
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml text/javascript; gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    # SSL
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!EXP:RC41RSA:1HIGH:!kEDH;

  # vHost-Konfigurationen
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

  # Leerer vHost (Default)
  server {
    server_name   _;
    listen   80   default;
    access_log   off;
    error_log        off;
        root /www/vhosts/defaulthost/www;

    # Error-Pages
    #include    error_pages.conf;

    location / {
      index   index.htm;
      rewrite ^   index.htm;
        }
    limit_req zone=antiddos burst=5 nodelay;
    }
}
```

**And here's the output of ls -ARl /www/**

```
ls -ARl /www/
total 2
drwxr-xr-x  5 www  www  5 20 Dez 00:48 vhosts

/www/vhosts:
total 5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       wheel      3 20 Dez 00:10 config
drwxr-x---  8 root       www        8 20 Dez 00:48 defaulthost
drwxr-x---  8 chris_www  chris_www  8 20 Dez 00:09 example.com

/www/vhosts/config:
total 1
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  16 20 Dez 00:10 vhost_port.conf

/www/vhosts/defaulthost:
total 9
drwxr-x---  2 root  www  2 20 Dez 00:50 certs
drwxr-x---  2 root  www  2 20 Dez 00:48 conf
drwxr-x---  2 root  www  2 20 Dez 00:50 log
drwxr-x---  2 root  www  2 20 Dez 00:48 sessions
drwxr-x---  2 root  www  2 20 Dez 00:48 tmp
drwxr-x---  2 root  www  3 20 Dez 00:48 www

/www/vhosts/defaulthost/certs:
total 0

/www/vhosts/defaulthost/conf:
total 0

/www/vhosts/defaulthost/log:
total 0

/www/vhosts/defaulthost/sessions:
total 0

/www/vhosts/defaulthost/tmp:
total 0

/www/vhosts/defaulthost/www:
total 1
-rwxr-x---  1 root  www  24 20 Dez 00:48 index.htm

/www/vhosts/example.com:
total 9
drwxr-x---  2 chris_www  chris_www  5 20 Dez 00:10 certs
drwxr-x---  2 chris_www  chris_www  2 20 Dez 00:09 conf
drwxr-x---  2 chris_www  chris_www  5 20 Dez 00:10 log
drwxr-x---  2 chris_www  chris_www  2 20 Dez 00:09 sessions
drwxr-x---  2 chris_www  chris_www  2 20 Dez 00:09 tmp
drwxr-x---  2 chris_www  chris_www  3 20 Dez 00:42 www

/www/vhosts/example.com/certs:
total 5
-rwxr-x---  1 chris_www  chris_www  757 20 Dez 00:10 example.com.crt
-rwxr-x---  1 chris_www  chris_www  603 20 Dez 00:10 example.com.csr
-rwxr-x---  1 chris_www  chris_www  887 20 Dez 00:10 example.com.key

/www/vhosts/example.com/conf:
total 0

/www/vhosts/example.com/log:
total 65
-rwxr-x---  1 chris_www  chris_www  23432 20 Dez 01:11 nginx.access.log
-rwxr-x---  1 chris_www  chris_www  40968 20 Dez 01:11 nginx.error.log
-rwxr-x---  1 chris_www  chris_www      0 20 Dez 00:10 php-fpmslow.log

/www/vhosts/example.com/sessions:
total 0

/www/vhosts/example.com/tmp:
total 0

/www/vhosts/example.com/www:
total 1
-rwxr-x---  1 chris_www  chris_www  24 20 Dez 00:34 index.htm
```

Comment: If 403 returned by nginx (not upstream) - reason should be in error_log

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
user www www;
worker_processes 8;
```

And this:

```
/www/vhosts:
total 5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root       wheel      3 20 Dez 00:10 config
drwxr-x---  8 root       www        8 20 Dez 00:48 defaulthost
drwxr-x---  8 chris_www  chris_www  8 20 Dez 00:09 example.com
```

Without looking further, I presume your intent is to have `nginx` serve `example.com` from `/www/vhosts/example.com`.

But how could it possibly do so, without having a permission to a read/execute?

You have to ensure user and/or group `www` have access to all directories leading to the content which they're supposed to serve.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to add the www user to the chris_www group, and presuming you also don't want to add the +x flag to example.com, you could consider using FreeBSD's Access Control List (ACL) support for UFS. I did a little write-up on it recently: http://pgib.me/blog/2014/01/06/freebsd-acls-ftw/